# Create Unique Makes Duplicate Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What I am trying to do is make a relationship from a person to an AWARDED Degree node.  There should only be one of these Degree nodes with `MBA`, and everyone that has an `MBA` will point to this one node.

The problem is, when I run this query with a `startNode` of a different person, it creates a new `Degree{value:'MBA'}` node. How can I have it all pointing to the same `MBA` node?

My Cypher Query:

```
START startNode=node(1)

CREATE UNIQUE
startNode-[:HAS_EDUCATION]->(nodeEducation1:Education{graduated_year:1901})

CREATE UNIQUE  nodeEducation1-[:AWARDED]->(a:Degree{value:'MBA'})

RETURN a;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create unique doesn't on its own try to match nodes [[1]](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-create-unique.html#create-unique-create-node-if-missing).
What you can do is use the [merge](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-merge.html#merge-merge-single-node-specifying-both-label-and-property) functionality to match the `Degree` Node (creating one only if necessary) and then `create unique` the relationship and intermediate nodes.

```
START startNode=node(9)
MERGE( phd:Degree {value: 'PHD'})
CREATE UNIQUE
startNode-[:HAS_EDUCATION]->(nodeEducation1:Education{graduated_year:1901})

CREATE UNIQUE  nodeEducation1-[:AWARDED]->phd

RETURN phd
```